# Reference: （彝语）杀只鸡，你死了我开心

Tags: topolect

I recently found out that there is a phrase in 彝语 (Yi) which equates to:

> 杀只鸡，你死了我开心

I tried finding some references to this online, but to no avail.

If the original Yi phrase is available I would like to see it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Slaughter a chicken as an offering to thanks gods" is a common expression in Chinese, meaning: "something to celebrate for; something to thanks gods for"

In Cantonese, it is 要劏雞還神

Example: 如果你死咗，我就要劏雞還神 ( if you died，I will have to celebrate / thanks the gods )

The wording differs from dialect to dialect. For example,  要劏雞還神 in Mandarin would be 要殺雞酬神 and in other dialects, including Yi,  屠 or 宰 may replace 劏 or 殺; other animal may replace chicken, but the basic premise would not be too far apart in writing.

Comment: 广州话普通话词典 has 劏雞還神 defined as (粵) 殺雞以酬謝神的恩典, 含“謝天謝地”之意。

Comment: off-topic: can we use 劏 in Cantonese like 宰 in Mandarin? i.e.; 宰了你！把你宰了！

Comment: Yes, you can say 我要劏咗你 ( I'll slaughter you) instead of 我要殺咗你( I'll kill you) in Cantonese . Both 劏 and 宰 mean "slaughter "(mainly of animal) .Using the term slaughter imply you are regarding other guy as an animal.